# How can I create a function to generate new variables based on values in different dataframe in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I would like to create a function like this (obviously not proper code):

```
forEach ID in DATAFRAME1 look at each row with ID in DATAFRAME2 {
  if DATAFRAME2$VARIABLE1 = something { 
    DATAFRAME1$VARIABLE1 = TRUE; 
    DATAFRAME1$VARIABLE2 = DATAFRAME2$VARIABLE2
  }
}
```

In plain text, I've got a list of individuals and a database with mixed information on these 
individuals. Let's say `DATAFRAME2` contains informations on books read `c(id, title, author, date)`. I want to create a new variable in `DATAFRAME1` with a boolean of if the individual has read a specific book (`VARIABLE1` above) and the date they first read it (`VARIABLE2`above). Also adding a third variable with number of times read would be interesting but not neccesary.

I haven't really done this in **R** before, mostly doing basic statistics and basic wrangling with **dplyr**. I guess I could use **dplyr** and join but this feels like a better approach. Any help to get me started would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post reproducible examples and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The following function does what the question asks for. Its arguments are

1. `DF1` and `DF2` have an obvious meaning;
2. `var1` and `var2` are `VARIABLE1` and `VARIABLE2` in the question;
3. `value` is the value of `something`.

The test data is at the end.

```
fun <- function(DF1, DF2, ID = 'ID', var1, var2, value){
  DF1[[var1]] <- NA
  DF1[[var2]] <- NA
  k <- DF2[[var1]] == value
  for(id in df1[[ID]]){
    i <- DF1[[ID]] == id
    j <- DF2[[ID]] == id
    if(any(j & k)){
      DF1[[var1]][i] <- TRUE
      DF1[[var2]][i] <- DF2[[var2]][j & k]
    }
  }
  DF1
}



fun(df1, df2, value = 4, var1 = 'X', var2 = 'Y')
#  ID    X  Y
#1  a   NA NA
#2  d TRUE 19
```

**Test data.**

```
set.seed(1234)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("a", "d"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:5], 4), 
                  X = sample(20, 20, TRUE),
                  Y = sample(20))
```